# Jquery auto increment to append(" ")

Tags: jquery, auto-increment

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                    $("#inputtext").append("<input type='text' name='photo_1'/><br />");
                                })
    })
```

i wanna photo_1 to auto increment as photo_1,photo_2,photo_3,...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some thing like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var count = 1;
    $("button").click(function(){
       $("#inputtext").append("<input type='text' name='photo_" + (count++) +"'/><br />");
    });
})
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GqDUw/)**

Comment: thanks for ur answer, but the name wouldn't become photo_1,photo_2,photo_3,... And just being photo_,photo_,photo_,...
Still having problem.

Comment: @SoeMoeNaing - Check my edited answer, there was unwanted single quote in the string I removed it. Now it should work fine.

Comment: Doens't work. I have still count == 1 and it doesn't increase

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function(){
  var i = 1; //Number to start
  while (i <= 10) {//number to end
    $("#inputtext").append("<input type='text' name='photo_" + i + "'/><br />");
    i++;
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, But just one click the 10 <input> come ,
I just need one click, one input,
How could i solve?

Comment: Thanks anyway, now i got the while formula :).